# Modifying Recipes for Boil Volume

Tags: hop-utilization, partial-boil, full-boil

I am modifying an extract recipe for a full volume boil. I understand how to use a brew calculator to calculate modified hop additions, but since my LHBS store sells hops in 1 oz bags, I'd rather not add 0.6 oz and throw away half the bag.

Are there other good approaches to make these changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not save the hops you don't use and use them in another brew?  Although vacuum sealing them is the best way, they'll keep fine for several months in a zip lock freezer bag.  Just squeeze out as much air as possible after you put the hops in the bag and keep the bag in the freezer.  That way your current beer gets the proper amount of hops and you aren't wasting the rest.